# Converting String to BigInteger

Tags: java, swing, biginteger

I am creating a messaging application using RSA encryption. Here I want to convert my ciphertext which is a string into a BigInteger . I have done this

```
String ciphertext = message.getText();

String receivedPlaintext = new String(decryption.decrypt(new BigInteger(ciphertext)));

message.setText(receivedPlaintext);
```

It works fine on the same window but on different window like when decrypting the received text it shows error like :

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "52485972 "
```

can you give me a solution ?

Comment: The exception's stacktrace printout is telling you *exactly* what is wrong, and key to solving this is learning to critically read it and learn from it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting numbers with whitespace around them, so you should trim those:

```
String receivedPlaintext = new String(
    decryption.decrypt(new BigInteger(ciphertext.trim()))
);
```